# In Unity (VR application), how do I make a Cloth object Grabbable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, openxr, cloth-simulation

I am trying to let the user character grab a GameObject that is supposed to behave like a cloth, with cloth physics simulation as well as gravity effects on it. For example, the user be able to pick up a handkerchief from a table (at any point on the handkerchief and using both hands).

As the cloth object is able to register collisions with sphere and capsule colliders, I tried out these things:

- Add XRGrabInteractable (that adds RigidBody) to the GameObject without touching anything else: does nothing (partly expected this to be the case)
- Add XRGrabInteractable and Box Collider to the GameObject. This sort of works but when I grab and move, say, one edge of that collider, the 'Cloth' and the skinnedmeshrenderer follow cloth physics and deform, but the box collider of course stays rigid, so I cannot grab the other end of the cloth that flopped down as there is no collider to that end.